# Looping in expo react native

Tags: react-native, expo

I want to play an audio sound an amount of time. Is there anyway that you can determine the number of time you can loop an audio? In expo, i only see a the state for a sound: isLooping: true. This will loop the sound endlessly, not a certain amount of time! Down here is my code on state of the sound and where i play the sound

```
//state of the sound
const { sound, status } = await this.recording.createNewLoadedSoundAsync(
      {
        isLooping: false,
        isMuted: this.state.muted,
        volume: this.state.volume,
        rate: this.state.rate,
        shouldCorrectPitch: this.state.shouldCorrectPitch
      },
      this._updateScreenForSoundStatus
    );

//play sound or pause sound when the button is pressed
_onPlayPausePressed = () => {
    if (this.sound != null) {
      if (this.state.isPlaying) {
        this.sound.pauseAsync();
      } else {
        this.sound.playAsync();
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [this](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av/#example-loop-media-exactly-20-times), it illustrates how you can loop exactly 20 times.

Hope this helps!